# Reading from a string List<>

Tags: c#, string, list, csv, streamreader

my application basically reads a CSV file which will always have the same format and I need to application to create a CSV file with different formatting. Reading and writing CSV file is not the issue, however the problem I am having is reading from the string array containing all the data from the CSV file.

For example: From the below, how can I get the system to get me the 4th value only: Value Date

[0] = "\"Book Date\",\"Reference\",\"Descript\",\"Value Date\",\"Debit\",\"Credit\",\"Closing Balance\""

This is how I am reading from CSV file.

```
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName));
        List<string> searchList = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            searchList.Add(line);
        }
```

Comment: Would using a 3pp lib such as https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the line and get the 4th value like this:

```
searchList.Add(line.Split(',')[3]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.100).aspx). It returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array.

```
var splitStrings = line.Split(",");

if (splitStrings.Length > 4)
{
   searchList.Add(splitStrings[3]);
}
```